# Add custom field to Jira search query using Atlassian.SDK

Tags: c#, jira, jql, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am using the Atlassian.Jira NuGet package in my web app.

I can successfully query Jira using built in fields for example Project, ResolutionDate etc. but I cannot use a custom field.

I have a custom field named "Organizations"  and I want to add this to my query where it is equal to a certain string.

Here is my query:

```
var issues = from i in jira.Issues.Queryable
where i.Created >= dateFrom &&
i.Created <= dateTo && i.Type != "Change" && i["Organizations"] == organization
select i;
```

---

I have tried the following:

```
i["Organizations"] == organization
```

> Returns 400. Operator ~ not supported.

```
i["Organizations"].ToString == organization
```

> Returns Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the
>   size of the collection.

Sounds like there is nothing to return but I can see issues in the portal.

I also tried:

```
i.CustomFields["Organizations"].Values[0] == organization
```

> 400. Response Content: {"errorMessages":["Error in the JQL Query: Expecting a field name but got ')'. You must surround ')' in quotation
>        marks to use it as a field name

Though I don't think it is supposed to be used this way.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the LiteralMatch instead of ==. LiteralMatch is like ~ operator in JQL.

```
where i.Created >= dateFrom &&
i.Created <= dateTo && i.Type != "Change" && i["Organizations"] == new LiteralMatch(organization)
select i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. I resolve by this query:

```
List<Issue> list = (from i in (IQueryable<Issue>)jira.Issues.Queryable
                                    where i.Project == ProcessConfiguration.ParentProjectKey
                                    && (DateTime)i.Created >= (DateTime)jiraSelectInputDto[0].FromDate
                                    && (DateTime)i.Created <= (DateTime)jiraSelectInputDto[0].ToDate
                                    && i["Customer"] == new LiteralMatch(cusProvince.Province)
                                    orderby i.Key descending
                                    select i).ToList();
```